# curl redirect login credentials protection

Tags: curl, password-protection

I am thinking about using curl on a website to login to different websites I own, so I found some example code online. Now my question is: Is it save to give a username and password this way. Else, what should I do instead?

```
$url_post = "http://localhost/joomla/joomlathree/index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login&lang=en";
$postdata = "username=".urlencode($uname)."&password=".urlencode($upswd)."&return=".urlencode($matches1[1][0])."&".urlencode($matches2[1][0])."=1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$results1 = curl_exec($ch);

$url_data = "http://localhost/joomla/joomlathree/index.php?option=com_users&lang=en"; //MOD REWRITE Disabled
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);

$results2 = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
echo ($error);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The curl operation is safe to use. However you should use https for sending around credentials because without they can be read from the request easily by others.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).